# How to Get if a Type in a many to many or one to many relationship with other Type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I tried to get if a type in a m2m/one2many relationship, for example i have two models Student and Course.

Student Model:

```
public class Student
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public ICollection<Course> CompletedCourses { get; set;}
   public ICollection<Course> FavoriteCourses { get; set;}
   public ICollection<Course> CreateCourses { get; set;}
}
```

Course Model

```
public class Course
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;} 
   public int CreateStudentId {get; set;}
   public virtual Student { get; set;}
   public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set;}
   public ICollection<Student> FavoriteByStudents { get; set;}
}
```

Now assume i got two types using reflection from two entities and i want to check if they are in a m2m/one2may relationship i used this code it returns true if the two types in a m2m relationship but i couldn't specifiy the property name, because in some cases two types have more than one relationship to the same type.
 this is my code trying to get if two types are on a m2m relationship form the MetadataWorkspace:

```
private bool IsInManyToManyRelaship(Type type1, Type type2, string navigationPropertyName)
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    var all_ssociations = metadata.GetItems<AssociationType>(DataSpace.CSpace);
    var m2m_ssociations = all_ssociations.Where(x => x.RelationshipEndMembers.Any(r => r.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many));
    return m2m_ssociations.Any(x => (x.RelationshipEndMembers[0].GetEntityType().Name == type1.Name && x.RelationshipEndMembers[1].GetEntityType().Name == type2.Name )
    || (x.RelationshipEndMembers[1].GetEntityType().Name == type1.Name && x.RelationshipEndMembers[0].GetEntityType().Name== type2.Name));
}
```